# Generar promedio en subgrupos en Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Para construir un diagrama de Media y Rango debo graficar los promedios de cada subgrupo, así que, dada una lista de números como puedo calcular el promedio en subgrupo de 3 y retorna los promedios de cada subgrupo en power bi...

De antemano, muchas gracias por la ayuda.